# Add vertical scroll bar to document-based Mac app's window

Tags: cocoa, scrollbar, nswindow, nsdocument

I'm looking at MyDocument.xib in Interface Builder and I can't for the life of me find how to add a vertical scrollbar.

It's set to 768x756 minimum size and 768x1024 maximum size. It starts out at minimum size (to support schools that use older MacBooks with 800px high screens), but the content does occupy 1024 height. So I need a vertical scrollbar to scroll the rest of the app window contents into view.

I tried setting the window contentSize, but that just makes the window larger.

Bit baffled by this as in every other environment in the world, not necessarily IDEs, it's a matter of ticking a box...

Comment: I'm fiddling around with this and am surprised at how difficult a time I'm having. It seems that NSScrollView doesn't resize itself to fill a window the way most views do. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Is Auto Layout turned on for your nib, or not? It seems like the way to accomplish this will depend.

Comment: Checked it, no difference but I think that's because the scroll bars are on the extra view and not the window/outermost view. The scroll bars display but are empty and dead. Not that I can make the scrollview a direct child of the window in any way. 'Display scrollbars if window shrunk to less than its contents' shouldn't be this hard, I must be doing something "not the Apple way".

Answer (score 1):

Select your document view object in Interface Builder and select Editor->Embed In->Scroll View.

Or you can just drag an NSScrollView from the object palette into your window.

Comment: Apparently I want normal stuff I can't have. Again. Embed menu contents are grayed out. Dragging into the window puts it at the deepest layer. Arranging manually lets me put it anywhere - except where I want it. It seems what I want is to replace the view with a scrollview containing a view and scrollbars. Which could have been achieved with two checkboxes. :/

Comment: I've put the document in the scrollview's view and put the scrollview in the window's view. Apart from IB changing my document's view measurements to negative values, what does not happen is scrollbars appearing as I shrink the window. Which is what I want.

Comment: My document object is inside a view inside the window. I selected it and I could embed it in a Scroll View, and it worked. Two scrollers were also added. They didn't appear when I ran the app, so I checked Enabled on them. Still no dice. What should I check?

Comment: In the scrollview, Show Horizontal Scroller and Show Vertical Scroller is also checked.

Comment: Show scrollbars is set to Always in System Preferences also.

Comment: A have a bunch of objects (views, buttons, labels). So I chose them all and embedded in a scroll view. Now all of my views does;t show on the scrollview.